# Visual C# windows forms constantly check and update value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox

I'm doing a project for college and have create a panel with a simple lunch menu. Each item of the menu if presented by a check box. What I wanted to happen was for the total to be changed every time a new item is checked or unchecked. This is the code I have tried using so far but it seems to freeze the program when I run it. I have tried using a while loop to constantly check if the check boxes are checked or un-checked.

There is a panel with the check boxes inside and a label at the bottom of the panel.

Am I on the right line in terms of using the while loop to check what the checked status of each check box is and update the label text accordingly?

```
private void plBistro_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            //create a variable to hold the total
            double bistotal = 0.0;

            while(bistotal != 99){
                //check if they chose a ham sandwich
                if(cbHamSandwich.Checked == true){

                    //if they did add 1.20 to the value of bistotal
                    bistotal = bistotal + 1.20;
                }

            string bistotalString = Convert.ToString(bistotal);

            lblBistroTotal.Text = bistotalString;
        }
        }
```

Comment: Don't use the Paint even to calculate something. Just Paint.

Comment: What do you mean when you say paint?

Comment: Just don't use the paint event at all. It's not relevant to your problem. Use the CheckedChanged event of the checkbox. You don't need a loop. Windows applications are event-driven. You don't poll for events (loop), you just sit and wait for them. When you loop, your app holds its breath and waits for you to stop looping.

Comment: to "Paint" means to draw a screen.  If you change the values of your controls, your controls will tell your form to fire the paint event.  If your paint event is changing the vaules of your controls, you're implementing an infinite loop where every time you paint, you change the values, which causes you to paint, which causes you to change values, which causes you to paint, which causes you to change values, etc. etc. etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an infinite loop in your code, plus the Paint event is not the place to do this calculation. You want something more like:

```
private void cbHamSandwich_CheckChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalcTotal();
}

private void CalcTotal()
{
    double bistotal = 0.0;

    if(cbHamSandwich.Checked == true)
    {
        //if they did add 1.20 to the value of bistotal
        bistotal = bistotal + 1.20;
    } 

    // more selected values to add to total

    lblBistroTotal.Text = bistotal.ToString("c");
}
```

Add `CheckChanged` events for each option that needs to change the total price.

Comment: Why did you use an array to store the total?

Comment: He didn't.  An array in C# is indicated by square brackets: int[] intArray;

Comment: Sorry stupid cap on, its a function that is called when each check box is clicked , thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're taking a wrong approach to this. The checkboxes should raise an event and an event handler should take care of maintaining the total.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that will cause an infinite loop, changing a label will cause a repaint...

add a handler for the CheckBox.CheckChanged event and do what you want in there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what's going on here is that accessing or setting something on the UI thread (either accessing cbHamSandwich, or setting the text on lblBistroTotal) is triggering a new paint event each time it is set, thus an infinite loop.  You should probably be doing this update in a timer, or listening to other UI events.

**Edit:**
Now that I look a little closer, it seems like the while loop itself is also a fundamental problem.  You're basically saying that you want to increase your total all the way up to at least 99 when the checkbox is checked (while the total isn't 99, if the checkbox is checked, keep adding).  But it **will** break out of that loop once it reaches 99.  That's not your most crucial problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give your checkboxes onchanged handlers..something like:

```
private void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  if (sender is CheckBox) { 
    CheckBox checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

    //do you checkbox accounting here
    if (checkbox.Checked){
      //blah
    }else{
      //blah
    }
  }
}

// elsewhere..assign event handler
chkBox.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkBox_CheckedChanged);
```

Answer (score 0):

The CheckedChanged and the CheckStateChanged events will be fired..
use it like this:

```
private void cbHamSandwich_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Verify(Check) the Checked property of the Checkbox and
    //Your Code Goes Here
}
```

and, Also :

```
private void cbHamSandwich_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Verify(Check) the CheckState property of the Checkbox and
    //Your Code Goes Here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, handling this in the paint event isn't really what you're going to want to do.  My advice is to put your code inside an event handler that all of your check boxes are wired to.  Obviously, a name more appropriate than "checkBox2_CheckStateChanged" would be better, but you can name the function whatever you like, really.

[image: Setting two controls to use the same event handler]

EDIT: Or you can make a CheckChanged event handler for each checkbox and call a function to calculate your totals.